# Download file without knowing file name

Tags: http

I have problem I cannot seem to find solution anywhere. From

```
somesite.net?id=xyz
```

I need to download some file. Url returns either file or JSON object with error message. If it returns file, how to get filename? I believe I'm missing something extremely obvious.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to list the code you are using so far, so that people can help

Comment: Well I did not have relevant code to show. Answer below is what I wanted to know. Thanks for effort

Comment: ok sure. however then it is mis-tagged, this is a plain http question

Comment: You are quite right about that. If you propose edit I will accept it. Or I can edit it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there *is* a file name (there doesn't have to be) then it would be in [the `Content-Disposition` header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition).  If there isn't, then you would need to provide a file name explicitly when saving it to the file system.

Keep in mind that HTTP isn't a file system.  What you're receiving isn't necessarily a "file" *per se*.  It's a body of data with headers that provide some information (meta-data) about that body of data.  One of those headers may contain a suggested name to use when saving that data to a file system, but it's not required.